# Value of Prime P in shamir secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

How the value of prime integer taken in Shamir's Secret sharing scheme. I have taken p which is greater than my secret and the no of shares. When i do calculation without modp then secret reconstruct happens successfully but when i do calculations modp then secret reconstruction is not happening.
Below is my example
Secret S=100
a1=3
a2=6
a3=7
Prime P=107
I had calculated 8 shares without modp. In this case secret 100 appears after reconstruction
S1(1,116)
S2(2,186)
S3(3,352)
S4(4,656)
S5(5,1140)
S6(6,1846)
S7(7,2816)
S8(8,4092)

But when i take f(x) mod 107 then secret doesn't appears as 100 instead some fraction value appears
.Request to suggest how prime no p is selected.

Comment: You want to use [modular multiplicative inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) for division when working in the prime field, not "normal" division as used for real numbers.

Comment: Without your details, we cannot help to find your mistakes, however the general rule is ;Without loss of generality, we can assume that our secret $S$ is an element of a prime finite field with order $t$ ( i.e. $t$ is a prime). Then we can set the bounds 
$$0 < k \le n < t \, \text{ and }\, S <t.$$